# Extracting phrases from a string

Tags: c#

I have a text file that I need to search and then print to screen certain phrases from it.

I can bring the text file into a string and find the index of thefirst part of the phrase like so;

```
int first = source.IndexOf(start-keyword);
```

Where source is the text file string and start-of-phrase is the first keyword I'm looking for.

However when I try to get the index of the end keyword I get stuck as sometimes the end keyword comes before the first keyword.

So I added the following bit to my code so it looks like:

```
int first = source.IndexOf(start-keyword);
string source2 = source.Substring(first, source.Length - first);
int last = source2.IndexOf(end-keyword) + end-keyword.Length;
phrases.Add(source.Substring(first, last));
```

Then the last line adds it to a list called phrases.

However I can't seem to find a satisfactory way to loop this as I start getting errors such as Out of range or not extracting the full phrase?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some text and some keywords.

Comment: Find the first and last index, and only substring if the order is correct.

Comment: There is an [overload of `IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) that takes a starting point for searching for the end keyword you may find useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at using [String.IndexOf Method(String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33) where you can specify the starting index value of the end of first start occurrence.

```
int last = source.IndexOf(end-keyword, first + start-keyword.Length ) 
           + end-keyword.Length;
```

Comment: I've also added the start-keyword length, in case the end-keyword is contained within the start-keyword, just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal candidate for **Regular Expressions**. 
Something like

```
"(\b[Pp]rogram\b)(.*)(\b[Vv]cvarsall\b)"
```

Should match

```
"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall"
```

in

```
"something Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall something"
```